# How to create a dict that can account for unknown keys

Tags: python

I have a dict like this:
`dict_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c' : 3}`. I have a list of dict keys like `list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', '*']`, where the `*` could be any value.
I would like to create a dict that can handle `*` and assign it a value of `0`

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use the standard `dict.get` method?

If you use `d.get(key, 0)` instead of `d[key]` it will give you the behaviour you want.

Example:

```
dict_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c' : 3}
dict_1.get('a', 0)    # returns 1
dict_1.get('Z', 0)    # returns 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be describing python's inbuilt [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

In your example, you could do the following;

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_1 = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
dict_1["a"] = 1

print(dict_1["a"])  # will print 1 as that's what is set.
print(dict_1["any key"])  # will print 0, as it hasn't been set before.
```

Because you want a default of `0` specifically, you could also use `defaultdict(int)` as `int()` returns `0`.

Comment: I only want dict_1 to return 0 only if the key is not `'a', 'b', 'c'`. If it's one of the three, return their respective value in `dict_1`

Comment: This works exactly the same as a dict, but when the value is unknown it'll quickly set it to whatever is returned by the parameter. So if you set a b and c to whatever they need to be, then you're already there. I've elaborated on this behaviour in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
# if key not in dict_1 will print 0
for key in list_1:
    print(dict_1.get(key, 0))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Code-only answers can be confusing, especially for beginner developers.  Consider editing your answer to include some explanation or context.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new dictionary for your requirement in following way:

```
dict_1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c' : 3}
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', '*']
# new dictonay with default value 0 for non-existing key in `dict_1`
new_dict = {l: dict_1.get(l, 0) for l in list_1}
```